# Popup Accordions not working With jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a **popup modal box** in which when the **user click on more information new modal box again popup on the same page** but it's not working properly I have tried everything,[Example of Popup Modal](https://usercentrics.com/)  if you **click more information new box open ups**, I am trying something like this.

Also please hide the popup on **accept and deny button and set a cookie for popup**

CSS

```js
< script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" > < /script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".footerr ul li:last-child").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popUpContain').css('display', 'none');
        $(".serviceMainContent1").css('display', 'block');
      })

      $("#closeInfoBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popUpContain').css('display', 'block');
        $(".serviceMainContent1").css('display', 'none');
      })

      $(".cat_btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".serv_btn a").css({
          "color": "#303030"
        });
        $(".serv_btn").css({
          "border-bottom": "none"
        });
        $('#services1').css('display', 'none');
        $("#category").css('display', 'block');
        $(".cat_btn a").css({
          "color": "blue"
        });
        $(".cat_btn").css({
          "border-bottom": "2px solid blue"
        });
      });
      $(".serv_btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".cat_btn a").css({
          "color": "#303030"
        });
        $(".cat_btn").css({
          "border-bottom": "none"
        });
        $("#category").css('display', 'none');
        $('#services1').css('display', 'block');
        $(".serv_btn a").css({
          "color": "blue"
        });
        $(".serv_btn").css({
          "border-bottom": "2px solid blue"
        });
      })


      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion1");
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
        });
      }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.popUp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

#language {
  width: 57px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.header1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container1,
.serviceMainContent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 595px;
  padding: 14px;
  box-shadow: -1px 16px 34px 2px #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.bodyy h3 {
  color: #303030;
}

.bodyy p {
  line-height: 19px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footerr>a {
  padding: 7px 90px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.footerr>.deny {
  background-color: #ededed;
  color: #303030;
}

.footerr>.accept {
  background-color: #0096FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.footerr>.deny:hover {
  background-color: #f4f2f2;
}

.footerr>.accept:hover {
  background-color: #4eabf7;
}

.footerr>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footerr>p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.footerr>ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footerr>ul li {
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #c4c2c2;
}


/* more information css   */

.serviceMainContent1 {
  height: 654px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: none;
}

.header1 a {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303030;
}

.categoryServices1 {
  height: 436px;
  width: 563px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #f8f7f7;
}

.cat_serv_btn,
.footerBtn {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.cat_serv_btn .cat_btn,
.cat_serv_btn .serv_btn,
.footerBtn a {
  width: 50%;
}

.cat_btn,
.serv_btn {
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.cat_btn:active,
.serv_btn:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.cat_btn a:active,
.serv_btn a:active {
  color: blue;
}

.cat_btn a:hover,
.serv_btn a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bodyy span {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}

.bodyy a,
.bodyy i {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footerBtn a {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  color: #303030;
}

.footerBtn a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footerBtn .save,
.footerBtn .deny {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.footerBtn .save:hover,
.footerBtn .deny:hover {
  background-color: #e7e6e6;
}

.footerBtn .close {
  background-color: #0096FF;
  color: #fff;
}

.footerBtn .close:hover {
  background-color: #4eabf7;
}


/* switch buttons */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider1 {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider1:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider1 {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider1:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider1.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider1.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* accordions */

.accordion1 {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.accordion1 div p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.accordion1 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion1:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0px 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

#services1 {
  display: none;
}


/* media query for mobile device */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 400px;
  }
  .footerr>a {
    padding: 5px 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popUp">
  <div class="container1" id="popUpContain">
    <div class="header1">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" width="20">
      <div style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: 10px;"><b>BCT-Touristik</b></div>
      <!-- <select name="" id="language">
                        <option value="DE">DE</option>
                        <option value="EN">EN</option>
    
                    </select> -->
    </div>
    <div class="bodyy">
      <h3>We value your privacy</h3>
      <p>We and our partners are using technologies like Cookies or Targeting and process personal data like IP-address or browser information in order to personalize the advertisement you see. This helps us to show you more relevant ads and improves your
        internet experience. We also use it in order to measure results or align our website content. Because we value your privacy, we are herewith asking your permission to use the following technologies. You can always change/withdraw your consent
        later by clicking on the settings button on the left lower corner of the page.</p>
    </div><br>
    <div class="footerr">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="http://www.testreise.de/die-malireise.de/datenschutz.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="http://www.testreise.de/die-malireise.de/impressum.html"> Legal Notice</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="http://www.testreise.de/die-malireise.de/bedingungen.html">Travel Condition</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="">More information</a></li>
      </ul><br>
      <a href="" class="deny" id="submit"><b>Deny</b></a>
      <a href="" class="accept" id="submit"><b>Accept and close</b></a>
      <p>Powered by <a href="https://www.bct-touristik.de/index.shtml">BCT-Touristik</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceMainContent1">
    <div class="headerBody">
      <div class="header1">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <select name="" id="language">
          <option value="DE">DE</option>
          <option value="EN">EN</option>
          <option value="PT">PT</option>
        </select>
        <a href="" id="closeInfoBtn">&#10006;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="bodyy">
        <h3>Privacy Settings</h3>
        <p>This tool helps you to select and deactivate various tags / trackers / analysis tools used on this website. </p>
        <span><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="">Legal Notice</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="cat_serv_btn">
        <div class="cat_btn">
          <a href=""><b>Categories</b></a>
        </div>
        <div class="serv_btn">
          <a href=""><b>Services</b></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="categoryServices1">
        <div id="category1">
          <div class="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion1">
              <div>
                <h5>Functional</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi at assumenda laborum rem fugiat accusamus voluptatem minus officiis eius, repellendus consequatur temporib</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span class="slider1 round"></span>
                                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel">
              <hr>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion1">
              <div>
                <h5>Functional</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi at assumenda laborum rem fugiat accusamus voluptatem minus officiis eius, repellendus consequatur temporib</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span class="slider1 round"></span>
                                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <hr>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion1">
              <div>
                <h5>Functional</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi at assumenda laborum rem fugiat accusamus voluptatem minus officiis eius, repellendus consequatur temporib</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span class="slider1 round"></span>
                                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel">
              <hr>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion1">
              <div>
                <h5>Functional</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi at assumenda laborum rem fugiat accusamus voluptatem minus officiis eius, repellendus consequatur temporib</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span class="slider1 round"></span>
                                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <hr>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="services1">
          <div class="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion1">
              <div>
                <h5>Services</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi at assumenda laborum rem fugiat accusamus voluptatem minus officiis eius, repellendus consequatur temporib</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span class="slider1 round"></span>
                                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel">
              <hr>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion1">
              <div>
                <h5>Services</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi at assumenda laborum rem fugiat accusamus voluptatem minus officiis eius, repellendus consequatur temporib</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span class="slider1 round"></span>
                                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <hr>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <br>
        <div class="footerBtn">
          <a class="save" href=""><b>Save</b></a>
          <a class="deny" href=""><b>Deny</b></a>
          <a class="close" href=""><b>Accept and close</b></a>
        </div>
        <p>Powered by <a href="">Usercentrics Consent Management</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Suggest me where I am going wrong in this I need to open another modal box on more info click?

Comment: Hi, there was some small mistake inside jquery code . Working [code](https://jsfiddle.net/t0pfwd3b/) .

Comment: @Swati thank you Swati but how to hide cookie poup  on close and accept  button ?

Comment: onclick of that button use `$("#popUpContain").hide()` to hide whole popup .